# get the current location in ios8

Tags: dictionary, ios8

i am using the code for getting the current location of user, its working with ios7 but not working with ios 8,this is my code, please tell me where it become wrong:

```
{


 //Start location manager
    mLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [mLocationManager setDelegate:self];
    //We actually fetch current location only once, next line almost pointless
   // [mLocationManager setDistanceFilter:100.0f]; // 100m
    //[mLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters]; // 100 m
    [mLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest]; // 100 m

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get current location. it is working in ios8 for me

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager

_locationManager.delegate = self; // we set the delegate of locationManager to self.
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];// add this line to update location
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS8 you should ask for Authorization before starting the `CLLocationManager`

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

In Addition you need to set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in your `Info.plit`.